# PHP insert character to certain position in string

Tags: php, str-replace

I have string (link)

And I want to insert certain character **{s}** to this string

Patern:     `http://i.imgur.com/filename{character}.extension`

**Before:**     `http://i.imgur.com/7k8t8pC.png`

**After**: `http://i.imgur.com/7k8t8pCs.png`

Comment: So you have a character and a position and you want to insert this character at this position or do you have the string already in this format: `http://i.imgur.com/7k8t8pC{character}.png` ?

Comment: I have string in this format: `http://i.imgur.com/7k8t8pC.png` ( Before string )

Comment: Will it always be at the end of the filename?

Comment: So you want to insert the `s` before the file extension?

Comment: str_replace() .png with {character}.png

Comment: Okay and you have a character AND a position where to insert it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hesitated to post this, but since you're using paths and what not:

```
$info = pathinfo($string);
$result = $info['dirname'] . "/" . $info['filename'] . "s." . $info['extension'];
```

Comment: Thats very neat and very simple and very flexible.

Answer (score 2):

how about this:

```
function addstring($ch,$string){  
    $array = explode('/',$string);
    $name = explode('.',end($array));
    array_pop($array);
    $new = implode('/',$array);
    return $new.'/'.$name[0].$ch.'.'.$name[1];
}
var_dump(addstring('CHAR','http://i.imgur.com/7k8t8pC.png'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a little trick with substr_replace:

```
$newstring = substr_replace( "http://i.imgur.com/7k8t8pC.png", "s", 26, 0);
```

Edit, a bit of explanation:
It allows to replace part of a string with another one. You pass the original string, the one to be inserted, the starting point and how many chars to replace. If, however, you pass 0, what happens is that it insert the second string into the first one at the given position.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$str = 'http://i.imgur.com/7k8t8pC.png';

echo preg_replace('/(\.png)/', 's$1', $str);
```

result:

```
http://i.imgur.com/7k8t8pCs.png
```

---

Or using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$str = 'http://i.imgur.com/7k8t8pC.png';

echo str_replace('.png', 's.png', $str);
```

result:

```
http://i.imgur.com/7k8t8pCs.png
```

Comment: dont use regular expressions when str_replace() will do